# Find y in terms of $t$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

So I am given this equation for the rate of a reaction:
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=y^2-8y+15$$ when $t=0, y=0$ [*what does this mean?*]

How can I proceed to find $y$ in terms of $t$?

I checked out this [site](https://mathforums.com/threads/how-to-solve-for-dy-dt.40507/) but I still don't get how you're supposed to find $y$ in terms of $t$ from it. Some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: there are constant solutions with $y=3$ and $y=5$ When $y(0) = 0$ you have one of the unbounded solutions; these are found by partial fractions.

Comment: the relationship is called an ordinary differential equation

Comment: @Moo why integrate? I get it so far but I don't get why you integrate it? And I already found the integration of it, it is $-\frac{1}{2}\ln \left|y-3\right|+\frac{1}{2}\ln \left|y-5\right|+C$ but what happens when you integrate the other side?

Comment: I bring dt to the other side so it becomes dy/dt, then i bring the equation to the other side so it becomes (y-3)(y-5)=dy/dt?

Comment: Nvm I was being silly, so It becomes $t+c$=$-\frac{1}{2}\ln \left|y-3\right|+\frac{1}{2}\ln \left|y-5\right|+C$ But how would I find C if it cancels both sides?

Comment: This is also known as an [autonomous differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)).

Comment: Why not just integrating on both sides?

Comment: @Rocca - note that each side integrates to it's *own* constant of integration.  So, on the left side you would make it $+ C$ and on the right $+ D$.  However, if you subtract $D$ from both sides, you get a single $C - D$, which is just one arbitrary constant minus another, which can be simplified to a single, unknown, arbitrary constant.  They do not "cancel each other out" but rather they are different but can combine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if everything has cleared up for you yet but i wrote the whole thing here if someone still needs it.

Original problem: $$ \dfrac{dy}{dt}=y^2-8y+15 \; , \; y=0 \; t=0 $$

The problem is asking for a **particular solution** of this ODE at $ y=0 \; t=0$

The dependent and and independent variable is shown like this: $y(t)$, where $y$ depends on $t$ so by plugging in the **initial contitions** $y=0$ and $t=0\;$ we get $y(0)=0$.
As we get our **general solution** these initial values should be plugged in and then we can solve our equation for the **constant of integration**.

By analyzing the specific initial values of our ODE we can find their unique particular solution which by the way can be graphically represented by an [**integral curve**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_curve) after writing our specific result of the constant of integration back to the general solution.

In some literature $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$ is often marked with $y'(t)$ or $\dot{y}$ .

This is a First Order Inhomogeneous ODE.

This can be solved by separation of variables so integrating both sides with respect to $dy$ and $dt$ respectfully.

$$ \int \dfrac{dy}{y^2-8y+15}= \int dt $$

This LHS integral can be simplified by [Partial Fraction Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Example_1).

$$\dfrac{1}{y^2-8y+15}= \dfrac{1}{(y-3)(y-5)}= \dfrac{A}{y-3} + \dfrac{B}{y-5}= \dfrac{A(y-5)+B(y-3)}{y^2-8y+15} \Rightarrow$$

where $A, B \in \mathbb{R} $

$$ 1= A(y-5)+B(y-3)= Ay-5A+By-3B$$
$$ y^0: \; 1 = -5A -3B $$
$$ y^1: \; 0 = A+B$$
Solving for $A$ and $B$ we get $A= -\frac{1}{2}$ and $B=\frac{1}{2}$

Substituting back our simplified problem becomes:

$$ \int \left(\dfrac{-\frac{1}{2}}{y-3}+\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}}{y-5}\right)\; dy = \int dt $$

which can be solved by u-substitution or by the $\int \frac{f'}{f}$ rule.

Note: *There are 3 integrals actually here, as from the property of linearity we integrate the LHS as two integrals so we'd technically get 3 constants of integration, 2 from $dy$ and 1 from $dt$.*

We get:

$$ -\dfrac{1}{2}\ln(|y-3|)+ \dfrac{1}{2}\ln(|y-5|)+C_1 = t+C_2$$

where $C_1, C_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, let $C_2-C_1=C$ which is a real number too.

$$ -\dfrac{1}{2}\ln(|y-3|)+ \dfrac{1}{2}\ln(|y-5|)= t+C$$
$$ -\ln(|y-3|)+ \ln(|y-5|)= 2(t+C)$$

By the quotient rule of logarithms:

$$  \ln\left(\left|\dfrac{y-5}{y-3}\right|\right)= 2(t+C)$$

After exponentiating both sides:

$$ \left|\dfrac{y-5}{y-3}\right| = e^{2(t+C)} $$

Ideally we'd want to solve the equation for $y$ explicitly but this solution is enough in our case.

Let's plug in $y(0)=0$, we can use any equation between $y$ and $t$ after the integrations.
Since we are trying to solve for $C$, let's choose $  \ln\left(\left|\frac{y-5}{y-3}\right|\right)= 2(t+C)$

We get

$$  \ln\left(\left|\dfrac{0-5}{0-3}\right|\right)= 2(0+C) $$

After a bit of cleaning up

$$ C = \dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{5}{3}\right)}{2} $$

Which is [approximately](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cdfrac%7B%5Cln%5Cleft%28%5Cdfrac%7B5%7D%7B3%7D%5Cright%29%7D%7B2%7D) $$ C \approx 0.25541281188 $$

Let's subtitute $C$ back into our general solution:

$$ \left|\dfrac{y-5}{y-3}\right| = e^{2(t+C)} $$

In an engineering class 2-3 decimal points are usually enough.

So our (approximated) solution is
$$ \boxed{ \left|\dfrac{y-5}{y-3}\right| = e^{2(t+0.256)} } $$

Whose [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qrhzvqxkyg) looks like this.

For a rather pure/rigourous mathematical setting they'd expect you to give an exact(non-approximated) closed-form solution, which would be:

$$ \boxed{\left|\dfrac{y-5}{y-3}\right| = exp\left({2t+\ln\left(\dfrac{5}{3}\right)}\right)} $$

( exp( for better visibility)

Answer (score 0):

''IF dy/dx is the rate of reaction, then y must be the concentration of product formed'' .

*Now, at t=0, y=0 means that when the reaction started( at t=0), the concentration of the products must be zero (y=0)*

For rest of the calculation you can refer to @lordcommander 's answer.

That is *THE BEST METHOD* if you have just got into integrations and differentiations.